# Filling a double[][] from the CSV file

Tags: java, arrays, csv

I have this CSV file:

```
World Development Indicators
Number of countries,4
Country Name,2005,2006,2007,2008,2009,2010,2011,2012,2013,2014
Bangladesh,6.28776238,13.20573922,23.46762823,30.16828408,34.35334451,44.94535882,55.19256723,62.82023906,74.42964608,80.03535051
"Bahamas, The",69.21279415,75.37855087,109.340767,102.7875065,101.2186453,118.8292307,81.5628489,80.65383375,76.05187427,82.29635806
Brazil,46.31418452,53.11025849,63.67475185,78.5549801,87.54187651,100.8810115,119.0023853,125.0018521,135.3050481,138.9514906  
Germany,94.55486999,102.2828888,115.1403608,126.5575074,126.2280577,106.4836959,109.6595675,111.5940398,120.9211651,120.4201855
```

I am trying to store countries' data(double once) into a matrix(double[][]). Here is the code that I have so far:

```
public double[][] getParsedTable() throws IOException {
    double[][] table = new double[4][10];
    String row;
    int indexRow = 0;
    int indexColumn = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    br.readLine();
    br.readLine();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null && !line.isEmpty()){
        line = br.readLine();
        String[] array = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
        for(int i = 1; i < array.length; i++){
            table[indexRow][indexColumn] = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
            indexColumn++;
        }
        indexColumn = 0;
        indexRow++;
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(table));
    return table;
}
```

I am getting an arror : NullPointerException at:

```
String[] array = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);
```

I cant figure out why. I tried different combinations. nothing seems to work. It seems to pick up the numbers from the CSV file and store them, but when I call:

```
System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(table));
```

it does not print out anything, hence I cant check if its stored properly or not. Could you tell me: `1. Why I am getting an error. 2. Why System.out.println does not print out an array.` Thanks

Comment: your CSV file format is not correct, headers must be in top of the line

Comment: @ArifMustafa this CSV file was provided by my instructor. I cant change it.

Comment: see this wiki [CSV example](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we assume that name of a country will not contain a digit and country name and numbers will be only comma separated, then following can be done without regex. I have changed file reading a little bit because it can run into issues.

```
public double[][] getParsedTable() throws IOException {
    double[][] table = new double[4][10];
    int indexRow = 0;
    int indexColumn = 0;
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
    br.readLine(); // ignore first line
    br.readLine(); // ignore second line
    br.readLine(); // ignore third line (contains title)
    String line;
    while (true) {
        line = br.readLine();
        if (line == null) break; // end of file reading

        int index = 0;
        while (true) {
            index = line.indexOf(",", index) + 1;
            if (Character.isDigit(line.charAt(index))) {
                break;
            }
        }

        // from index, line is expected to contain comma separated numbers
        String[] array = line.substring(index).split(",");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            table[indexRow][indexColumn] = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
            indexColumn++;
        }
        indexColumn = 0;
        indexRow++;
    }
    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(table));
    return table;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Arrays.deepToString is wrong.  You are passing in an array of primitives.  When you pass it in, you pass in double[][].  This is interpeted as Object[] where the objects are double[], so it will try to print double[] objects, and not print doubles.

One solution is to create an array Double[][].

Change

```
 double[][] table = new double[4][10];
```

to

```
 Double[][] table = new Double[4][10];
```

Autoboxing will convert each double to a Double.  Since Double is an object and not a primitive, deepToString will print out each Double individually.  If you read the javadoc for deepToString it explains that it operates recursively on arrays of reference type, not on primitive arrays.

If you want to stick with double[][]

```
for (int i = 0; i < table.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < table[i].length; j++) {
        System.out.print(table[i][j]);
        System.out.print(' ');
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: That's because if i do line.split(",") i will have an error once readLine() hits "Bahamas, The", since it contains characters inside.

Comment: I see.  In that case, you know you want the last 10 entries in each row.  So no matter how many entries you end up with, take the last 10.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not solve any of my problems

Comment: ok, one more solution for you, your use of deepToString is wrong.

Comment: how is it wrong? I thought it's supposed to print out the matrix.

Comment: the issue here is that I have to return double[][]. Is there any other way to print it out?

Answer (score 1):

In the csv, first 3 lines are not real country's data. So read in `line-4` before `while` loop starts.

In while loop, first finish the processing of `line` string first. Eg: regular expression check & assign split data into `table`.

Then only read in `next line` at end of `while` loop, to be processed in next iteration.

Feel free to try this out:

```
public double[][] getParsedTable() throws IOException {
    double[][] table = new double[4][10];
    int indexRow = 0;
    int indexColumn = 0;

    // check whether you need to handle any exception for this
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

    String line = null;

    try {
        // line 1-3 are not real country's data
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();
        br.readLine();

        // first country data begin at line 4
        line = br.readLine();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    while (line != null && !line.isEmpty()) {            
        String[] array = line.split(",(?=(?:[^\"]*\"[^\"]*\")*[^\"]*$)", -1);

        for (int i = 1; i < array.length; i++) {
            table[indexRow][indexColumn] = Double.parseDouble(array[i]);
            indexColumn++;
        }

        indexColumn = 0;
        indexRow++;

        // read next line only at end of loop, not beginning of loop
        // line is ready to be processed at next iteration
        try {
            line = br.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    System.out.print(Arrays.deepToString(table));
    return table;
}
```